# Is this PMF or PDF?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, markov-process

I am reading a technical report on expectation-maximization (EM) algorithm (http://melodi.ee.washington.edu/people/bilmes/mypapers/em.pdf) and I am confused about something.

For HMMs, it defines $b_j(o_t)=P(O_t=o_t\mid Q_t=j)$ ($O$ observation, $Q$ state). However, for the case of using Gaussian mixture models for observation distribution, it defines $b_j(o_t)=\sum_{l=1}^Mc_{jl}N(o_t\mid \mu_{jl},\Sigma_{jl})$ where $N$ denotes Gaussian/normal PDF I presume. The problem is, it looks to me like the latter definition of $b_j(\cdot)$ is a PDF not a PMF, whereas the original definition implies that it's a PMF.

Comment: With conditioning, a continuous variable can turn into a discrete variable, in a certain sense. But that doesn't appear to be happening in context: they mention that they're looking at two different types of output distribution, one discrete, and the other arising from these multivariate Gaussians.

Comment: It looks to me like a PDF, but what is the "original definition" you're referring to? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: b_j is first defined on page 7, second last paragraph

Answer (score 0):

The latter definition is a PDF. It's the continuous version of the distribution $b_j$ of observations for state $j$. The discussion at the bottom of page 7 (and continues to top of page 8) says:

> There are two forms of output distributions we will consider. The first is a discrete observation
>   assumption where we assume that an observation is one of $L$ possible observation symbols.... The second form
>   of probably distribution we consider is a mixture of $M$ multivariate Gaussians for each state...

(note the typo "probably" :)

Comment: But he can't just change it to PDF - that would break all previous derivation including forward/backward algorithms which are used to update the Gaussian parameters. Also see for instance the unnumbered equation after eq 10 where he still seems to be using b_j like a PMF

Comment: IIRC the forward/backward algorithms for HMMs look the same for discrete and continuous outputs, because manipulations using conditional probability take the same form either way. It appears the author is adopting pmf notation, even for continuous outputs, to avoid having two sets of formulas. I've seen expositions of the EM algorithm that similarly adopt a uniform notational convention: the author [Manning] uses p(x) to denote both discrete and continuous distributions and says "we do not need to specify anything further about these variables, such as whether they are discrete or continuous."